# Installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

I have purchased Windows 7 Ultimate with two DVDs 32 bit & 64 bit with one key. I wish to try 32 bit first & 64 bit later. Can i use same key for 64 bit software later on same computer?

Comment: Install the 64 bit version, there is no reason to install the 32 bit one except if your CPU don't support 64 bit.

Answer (score 3):

As long as it is reinstalling, on the same computer moreover, you can use the same key.

32 bit or 64 bit edition makes no difference in this matter.

**Edit:** Note that if your computer is capable to use 64 bit, there is no actual reason to try the 32 bit. They are about the same, besides that 64 will allow you to use more RAM (over 3gb), and some programs will have improved performances. But besides, there is no functional difference between the both. Eventually, if you use some exotic hardware, you will have difficulties to find drivers for a 64 bit system, and that would eventually be a reason to stay on 32. But other than that, I don't really see a reason to install 32.

If someone could add on that in comments, it would be nice, as I could eventually be wrong about some details.

Comment: Fine I got clear answer. Thanks as I am using Windows XP Professional at present & have purchased Windows 7 Ultimate & have no experience using either of the two operative systems.Now I can try one by one. Thanks again

Comment: I agree...go 64bit if you have a 64bit CPU (Pentium D+, Athlon64+).  I have never run into a situation where hardware I own didn't work.  Having only 3GB of useable RAM today is lame.  

Win7 ultimate also has a component that will run a full copy of XP as a virtual machine, but you will need a CPU with virtualization support (and it must be enabled in BIOS).    

In the VM session of XP in win7, it will run 16bit code and allow the installation of 32bit drivers (at least in my case for a Juniper VPN clinet that was 32bit only).  It's pretty slick, really.

Comment: I've heard of programs busting on 64-bit, though (I don't know why). Any insight?